# Android testing: How to change application before actvity is created?

Tags: android, android-testing

When writing an android test case how can I call some methods on my application object before the activity is created? My test class extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

Some of the things I've tried are

- **Looking for a method my test case can override**. I don't see one.
- **Creating a test activity that extends the app's activity**. I dont think I can do this without adding the test activity to the real application's manifest.
- **Getting the application inside of my test's setUp() method**. I can't find any way to access the application without first creating the activity

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're trying to do. ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is not designed to do it. You need something like Robotium that can invoke your Application object first, before your Activity object is created.

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, except in a few cases, is designed to test things *within* the Activity, and not its interaction with things outside the Activity. Unit testing in Android isn't perfect.

I also question why you need something from Application. Whenever someone mentions Application, a warning light goes off in my head. I rarely see code that uses Application, and 90% of the time the developer should have used something else.

Comment: Can you explain how I would solve the problem using Robotium? The reason I need something from Application is that the app I'm testing has implemented some important functionality in a subclass of Application. I need to set that up correctly to make sure the activity behaves the same every time the test runs.